# What is the most common pronunciation of "Sandra" in British English?

Tags: pronunciation

When I meet someone called "Sandra" I never know whether to pronounce their name "Sand-ra" or "Sahn-dra". I'm guessing it used to be "Sahn-dra" but with the influence of Sandra Bullock more people now seem to say "Sand-ra". I think this is especially so in Australia where, in NSW at least, they say "dance" not "dahnce". Here in New Zealand I'm not so sure.

Comment: In Britain, Northerners say *Sand-ra*, where Southerners say *Sahn-dra*. Sandra Bullock was born in Virginia, so I guess it should really depend what the local accent is there. But I'll continue to refer to her as *Sand-ra*, just as I call the capital of France *Pa-riss* - in defiance of the inhabitants, who insist on calling it *Pa-ree*.

Comment: ...but note that when you *meet* someone called anything at all, good manners dictate that you do your level best to reproduce the sound of their name the way they give it to you.

Comment: ...only problem is you have to be listening (actively) when they introduce themselves - I never am :(

Comment: This is one case where [Yahoo Answers](http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080527121938AAt4YrC) *might* be helpful.

Comment: @drɱ65 δ: Der... Most of that *Yahoo Answers* thread is taken up with bloody Northerners saying that poncy Southerners with their long a's are just talking "posh".

Comment: Brits don't even agree on how to pronounce _bath_.

Answer (score 2):

There's [actually a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xoz9nBBJjI) that demonstrates how to pronounce both "Cassandra" and "Sandra" with a British accent.

Answer (score 0):

My parents and I have always pronounced my name
 Sand-ra BUT when my mom was mad and she said
"Sahn-dra", I knew I was in trouble!

Comment: Do you mean that in the first case it started out like the word *sand* but in the second started out more like it rhymed with *fond*?